# MySQL & Cleaning up a chain of "LIKE" operators

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, refactoring

I've created a stored procedure that combines a set of book related tables and then returns results based on matches from more than one of a book's various attributes.

For example:
If I search for the word "fall", then the query might return books with titles and publishers containing the word "fall".

### Code:

The procedure I currently have is as follows...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE library.SearchForBooks(IN searchTerm varchar(50))
begin
    select bookID,title,series_name,series_part,first_name,middle_name,last_name,publisher_name,isbn,edition,copyright,genre_type,genre_name,format,pages,language_name,notes 
    from book 
    where title like concat('%',searchTerm,'%')
        or copyright like concat('%',searchTerm,'%') 
        or publisher_name like concat('%',searchTerm,'%') 
        or first_name like concat('%',searchTerm,'%')
        or middle_name like concat('%',searchTerm,'%')
        or last_name like concat('%',searchTerm,'%');
END
```

**NOTE:**

The actual stored procedure has a fair bit more going on within it but this is the section that's relevant. I can include more if it's needed.

### Explanation

The part I want to focus on is that series of "OR" operators. As it stands, they seem really sloppy and I'd like to clean it up. One thing I tried was concatenating the three separate parts of the author's name and then using *LIKE* in this manner. `or concat(first_name,' ',middle_name,' ',last_name) like concat('%',searchTerm,'%');` but this only had a mixed success rate. Sometimes it worked like it was supposed to and other times it wouldn't return books with values that I know for a fact are in the database.

Is there a way to store the `concat('%',searchTerm,'%')` as a variable in such a way that it can then be used without causing any errors? Something like `or copyright like savedVariable`? That would go a long way and I tried implementing it but I kept getting syntax errors.

**It should be noted that the procedure actually does work as it's intended to. My question is one of curiosity and attempting to create much cleaner code.**

I'm still quite new to MySQL and don't know all the nuances of the the language so I apologize if this is a very dumb question. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using [fulltext indexing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)?

Comment: *If I search for the word "fall", then the query might return books with titles and publishers containing the word "fall".* Not word but substring. This substring may be a part of another word (falling, rainfall and so on).

Comment: @BillKarwin I hadn’t considered it. I’ve never heard of it before but it does seem to have potential. I’ll do more research into this and give it a shot.

Comment: @Akina That’s intended as well. I want it to search for any possible matches. My example was too simplistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to store the `concat('%',searchTerm,'%')` as a variable in such a way that it can then be used without causing any errors? Something like `or copyright like savedVariable`?

Easily.

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM table
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT CONCAT('%',searchTerm,'%') AS pattern ) pattern
WHERE table.column LIKE pattern.pattern
  ...
```

From the other side this makes no sense - the result of `CONCAT('%',searchTerm,'%')` where `searchTerm` is a variable is totally a constant during definite query execution, and it is evaluated once during the execution plan building, not on the execution stage.

Comment: I added the line and made the needed changes to each of the OR operators and it worked very nicely. Every search I make is still returning everything I expect but now with a much cleaner appearance. Thanks! I have one other question though. Your mention of Execution Plans and Execution stages has me going down a major rabbit hole of documentation reading since these are terms I've never heard of before. My question is this, is the `CROSS Join ( Select Concat() AS pattern) pattern` line a part of these two concepts? It seems like a very stripped down query but I can't be sure what it is exactly

Comment: @TeaDrinker No, this is a subquery only. Non-dependent subquery which does not use any table. So it is evaluated during the planning and then used as derived table during the execution. You may see this in the execution plan. And when such subquery contains not one but a bunch of rows then the server may even auto-index it for to improve total query execution. Look for EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN ANALYZE outputs.